# Точка входа в процедуру не найдена в библиотеке

Tags: c++, msys2

Я хочу использовать tgbot-cpp в windows. Компилирую с помощью msys2, но при запуске из cmd выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если запускать из msys2 в cmd, то все работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как запускать exe-шник из cmd.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Во-первых текст стоит постить исключительно в виде текста, а не картинок. Во-вторых, все dll, от которых зависит исполняемый файл, необходимо копировать в папку с исполняемым файлом.

Comment: При компиляции ни одного dll не подключается, я не понимаю почему винда называет exe-шник dll

Comment: mingw по-умолчанию подключает целую кучу dll, прежде всего рантайм. dll и exe - это фактически одно и то же, разница только в точке входа и манифестах

Comment: как понять какой dll нужен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша программа подхватывает неправильную версию какой-то из dll, которые использует.

Почему в терминале MSYS2 все работает, а в CMD нет? Разница только в PATH - в первом случае первый элемент в PATH - это `/mingw64/bin`, в которой как раз лежат правильные версии всех нужных dll.

Решение такое:

- Ставите себе пакет `mingw-w64-x86_64-ntldd`.
- Командой `ntldd -R my_program.exe` узнаете список всех dll, которые ваша программа использует.
- Из них выбираете только те, которые лежат в `/mingw64/bin`, остальные игнорируете.
- Получившиеся dll копируете из `/mingw64/bin` в папку, где лежит ваш экзешник.

---

Если не помогает, тогда делаете вот что:

- В выводе `ntldd` ищете все `.dll`, лежащие в `C:\Windows` (или вложенных папках).
- Потом руками открываете `/mingw64/bin` и смотрите, какие `.dll` там есть.
- В идеале одинаковых `.dll` быть не должно. Если они есть, то удаляете их из `C:\Windows`. Их там быть не должно, но некоторые кривые инсталлеры (или неразумные программисты) могут их туда положить.
- Потом повторяете действия из первой половины ответа.

Comment: спасибо, помогло